# Field in @techreport

Tags: bibtex, bibentry

I got this `@techreprot` on my `.bib` file:

```
@techreport{NortheastGroup,
  author      = {{Northeast Group LLC}},
  title       = {Electricity Theft and Non-Technical Losses: Global Markets, Solutions and Vendors},
  institution = {Northeast Group LLC},
  month = {May},
  year        = {2017}
}
```

As result, i am getting this:

[image]

What entry is related to that [S.1.]? And how can i remove it?

Comment: the generation of the text is purely implemented in the `bst` bibtex style you are using, about which you have given no information.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am using `\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}`, it is related to the style `\bibliographystyle{abnt-alf}`?

Comment: there is no `abnt-alf.bst` in the texlive distribution, you would need to provide a link or better copy the thing in to a code block if you want anyone to comment on it. You are currently asing how to change the output of a program without showing your input or the program, which makes it difficult to answer.

Comment: Off-topic: It'a not correct to use the `@techreport` entry type for the entry at hand. I suggest you use `@misc` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real cause of the problem you've encountered is that you're using an inappropriate entry type for the publication at hand.

- The `@techreport` entry type should be used exclusively for working papers, discussion papers, etc that are part of a series and are given a number by an institution (such as an academic department, a school, or even an entire organization.
- The entry at hand doesn't seem to fit this requirement at all. Hence, I suggest you use the catch-all `@misc` entry type -- unless you can find an even more appropriate entry type. (Not having access to the publication, I'm not in a position to decide what might be more appropriate than `@misc`.)

By not using the `@techreport` entry type, you get rid of the `[S.1]` issue automatically.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{NortheastGroup,
  author      = {{Northeast Group LLC}},
  title       = {Electricity Theft and Non-Technical Losses: 
                 Global Markets, Solutions and Vendors},
  month       = {May},
  year        = {2017}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}
\bibliographystyle{abntex2-alf}

\begin{document}
\cite{NortheastGroup}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Totally agree. I just saw a `@techreport` from the World Bank that i am also using as reference, and it has a number in it. Hence, the Northeast Group reference i'm using is not a techincal report. I'll use it as a `@misc`.

Answer (score 3):

You provided no link but I am assuming you are using the BST file from

https://github.com/abntex/abntex2/blob/master/bibtex/bst/abntex2/abntex2-alf.bst

That has, near the start

```
 FUNCTION {bbl.no.address} {"[S.l.]"}
```

I'm not sure if the abbreviation means more in Portuguese than English?
So you could make a copy of this file with that string replaced by `""` or (probably better) add an `address` field to your `bib` entry.

Comment: Phelype suggests  S.l. == Sem local == No location/address

Comment: Even better than "adjusting" the `bbl.no.address` function in the bst file would be to start using a more appropriate entry type...

Comment: @Mico yes probably right although I'll leave this here as it shows where the S.l. string comes from